# Creating a developer test app

Tags: feature-request

Every time I want to ask a question I struggle to sanitise and simplify code so that others have something to look at. For posing the last question I asked, I decided to create a test project and I wondered whether (or perhaps, how) we could all maintain a project that offers all the features, and complexities we all deal with.

It [has been suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074950/creating-a-developer-test-app) that [thunderhub](https://github.com/jeresig/thunderhub/commits/master) might be a good place to start.  perhaps a SourceForge thing could work too.

In any case, it would be useful because we could all read through its code to learn the stuff and the more advanced people who answer questions on SO could use it to just point: "yeah, that's been done, just look at the Test Project, controller blah blah, etc." (in the case of an MVC3 app)

thoughts anyone?

Comment: *"maintain a project that offers all the features, and complexities we all deal with."* Sounds like a **hugely complicated** app. What language would we maintain it with? What framework(s)? Who decides which features get implemented? How in the world is pointing people to an utterly *monolithic* code-base going to help them understand the answer to their *specific* programming question?

Comment: When I first made this suggestion on the regular SO, I was focused very specifically on a test app for MVC3+Razor+EF - to be more general, I guess a collection of apps in whatever languages/platforms anyone cares about could be maintained

Comment: @Cody Gray, "Who decides which features get implemented?" - anyone with an interest

Comment: incidentally... I've been voted down.  does that affect my reputation?

Comment: +1 @ekkis I see no reason either obvious or given as to why your question was voted down. Perhaps someone simply misunderstood. Unless others voted it down, shame on those who said it was a good question and did not vote it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like this idea, but as a community project, not a SO feature.  This would be especially cool if we made something that was a useful OSS product in addition to being a talking point.

Comment: +1 for community project.

Comment: I originally [made the suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074950/creating-a-developer-test-app) in the regular SO but it was suggested I do it here instead (in fact, the thread was closed over there and moved here)

Comment: @ekkis SO is ONLY for programming Q&A. Talking about the site is for meta.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree that the text editor should be able to replace variable names with generic names etc, for the sake of protecting code, but this request is a bit much for a request of the SO team.

Comment: ok, so maybe this isn't really a job for SO.  I hadn't meant it to be... Bill the Lizard moved my original posting here... perhaps you can move it back where it belongs